# How to load data from database for viewpager

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-viewpager, android-room

In simpler terms, I have a viewpager2 which is supposed to display words and their meanings and users can be able to search and go a specific word just like a dictionary application. The problem is that I have a very huge database of a million words and loading it at once that's forever and slows the app down.
What's the best way to implement this?

My idea was to load five words at a time and load another set if the last word is reached but this seems impractical if the user search for another word. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

Before of all load it in another thread, and also try to load by limiting result